# How to keep .Net HttpWebRequest from using IP

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I build my request and provide a domain name, e.g. 'http://webservices.mydomain.com/test'

Problem is HttpWebRequest automatically resolves/translates to an IP address when submitting.  Deployment is within a very large Fortune 500 corporation with a security policy that IP address requests are never allowed so the request fails.  I need the HttpWebRequest to make its request with the domain name, not an IP address, is there a way to force it to keep the domain name when requesting?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Computers ONLY communicate with other computers via an IP address. Domain Names were created as a convenience for us humans to easily remember things. `www.pepsi.com` is a lot easier to remember then `165.254.29.9`. Computers can only communicate via IP addresses.

Comment: Only their proxy servers are trusted with domain/IP translation; they reject a direct submission of external IP addresses.

Comment: Then you need to hook in the proxy.

Comment: Not sure what hook in the proxy means.  And I'm not in a position to make demands of proxy config or security exceptions here.

Comment: You need to talk to the proxy, not to the website directly. You can configure the proxy in web.config.

Comment: Hey 'usr', the proxy address in the web.config did the trick.  Post as an answer rather than a comment and I'll give you the credit. Thanks.